Fix Metadata on a .mov file?
I have a .mov file that I believe has corrupted metadata. Every player thinks its duration is 1 second, but it's really over a minute long.
I've tried converting it with ffmpeg -i input.mov output.mp4 and Handbrake, but neither worked. I get a 1-second-long output file.
Googling for this topic lists a variety of apps which want you to buy a subscription to use them, I just need to fix this one instance.
Any suggestions welcome.
(Sonoma 14.4.1 on an M1 MacBook)
Update 1 - ffprobe output
Here's the output of ffprobe:
ffprobe version 6.0 Copyright (c) 2007-2023 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)
  configuration: --prefix=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/6.0 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librist --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-videotoolbox --enable-neon
  libavutil      58.  2.100 / 58.  2.100
  libavcodec     60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
  libavformat    60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
  libavdevice    60.  1.100 / 60.  1.100
  libavfilter     9.  3.100 /  9.  3.100
  libswscale      7.  1.100 /  7.  1.100
  libswresample   4. 10.100 /  4. 10.100
  libpostproc    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x157e05a40] Found duplicated MOOV Atom. Skipped it
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'P3160054.mov':
  Metadata:
    creation_time   : 2002-03-16T18:29:10.000000Z
    com.apple.quicktime.player.movie.audio.gain: 0.980469
    com.apple.quicktime.player.movie.audio.treble: 0.000000
    com.apple.quicktime.player.movie.audio.bass: 0.000000
    com.apple.quicktime.player.movie.audio.balance: 0.000000
    com.apple.quicktime.player.movie.audio.pitchshift: 0.000000
    com.apple.quicktime.player.movie.audio.mute:
    com.apple.quicktime.player.movie.visual.brightness: 0.000000
    com.apple.quicktime.player.movie.visual.color: 1.000000
    com.apple.quicktime.player.movie.visual.tint: 0.000000
    com.apple.quicktime.player.movie.visual.contrast: 1.000000
    com.apple.quicktime.player.version: 7.6.6 (7.6.6)
    com.apple.quicktime.version: 7.7.3 (2943.14) 0x7738000 (Mac OS X, 10.11.6, 15G22010)
    original_format : Digital Camera
    original_format-eng: Digital Camera
    comment         : OLYMPUS DIGITAL CAMERA
    comment-eng     : OLYMPUS DIGITAL CAMERA
  Duration: 00:00:00.07, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3016430 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x3](eng): Video: mjpeg (Baseline) (jpeg / 0x6765706A), yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 320x240, 2334 kb/s, 15 fps, 15 tbr, 600 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2024-04-23T15:42:32.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Video Media Handler
      vendor_id       : olym
      encoder         : Photo - JPEG
  Stream #0:1[0x4](eng): Audio: pcm_u8 (raw  / 0x20776172), 8000 Hz, 1 channels, u8, 64 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2024-04-23T15:42:32.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Sound Media Handler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]


What does ffprobe say about the video? How do you know it is a minute long?

I added the ffprobe output. I know the file is over a minute long from memory, and the fact that the file is 25MB (old and small, yes, but there is data there)

The bitrate looks impressive :-/
